# Solving Nonlinear Algebraic Equation

Tags: equation-solving

What is wrong with the code below? Mathematica is taking a long time trying to solve it.

```
Solve[(-2 Sqrt[1 - x^2] + (2 - 1.00 x^2) Sqrt[1 - 0.25` x^2]) (-2 + 
      0.25` x^2 - 4 Sqrt[1 - 0.33` x^2] Sqrt[1 - 0.25` x^2] + 
      3 (1 - 0.08 x^2) (1 + Sqrt[1 - 0.25` x^2])) - (2 - 
      1.00 x^2) (2 - x^2) (2 Sqrt[1 - 0.25` x^2] + 
      Sqrt[1 - x^2] (1 - 3 Sqrt[1 - 0.08 x^2])) == 0, x]
```

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. The introductory [book](https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/2nd-ed/) written by the inventor is a good learning resource. There is a [fast intro for math students](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-math-students/en/) as well as a [fast intro for programmers](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-programmers/en/) to choose from.

Answer (score 2):

It solves it fast if you use Reals. Also you really should use Exact input with `Solve`

```
input = (-2 Sqrt[1 - x^2] + (2 - 1.00 x^2) Sqrt[1 - 0.25` x^2]) (-2 + 
      0.25` x^2 - 4 Sqrt[1 - 0.33` x^2] Sqrt[1 - 0.25` x^2] + 
      3 (1 - 0.08 x^2) (1 + Sqrt[1 - 0.25` x^2])) - (2 - 
      1.00 x^2) (2 - x^2) (2 Sqrt[1 - 0.25` x^2] + 
      Sqrt[1 - x^2] (1 - 3 Sqrt[1 - 0.08 x^2])) == 0

Solve[Rationalize[input], x, Reals]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or use Numerical solver

```
NSolve[input,x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]